# How to structure (refactor) main loop in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, refactoring, wxwidgets, glm-math

How do you guys usually structure your main loop (loop where all draw calls are called)?

For example:

In my program I am drawing a human object. When you are left clicking on object 3 arrows appear (X, Y and Z) and with the help of these arrows you are able to change position of an object in space. On right click 3 rotation axes appear and again by click on them and moving your mouse you will be able to rotate object around its center.

Human object:

[image]

Right mouse click on human object:[image]

Left mouse click on human object

[image]

Main loop:

```
void MyGLCanvas::draw(wxDC& dc)
{
    wxGLCanvas::SetCurrent(*glContext);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glm::mat4 model, view, projection;
    model = glm::translate(model, modelPos);
    view = fpsCamera->getViewMatrix();
    projection = fpsCamera->getProjectionMatrix(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    color = glm::vec4(0.310f, 0.747f, 0.185f, 1.0f);
    glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 lightColor = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glm::mat4 initialPhantomRotationMatrix, phantomRotationMatrix_x, phantomRotationMatrix_y, phantomRotationMatrix_z, axisTransformation;
    initialPhantomRotationMatrix = glm::rotate(initialPhantomRotationMatrix, -glm::pi<float>() / 2.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    initialPhantomRotationMatrix = glm::rotate(initialPhantomRotationMatrix, -glm::pi<float>(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    phantomRotationMatrix_x = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(-0.3f, 1.0f, -0.05f)) * glm::rotate(phantomRotationMatrix_x, rotationAngle.x * glm::pi<float>() / 180.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) * glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(0.3f, -1.0f, -0.05f));
    phantomRotationMatrix_y = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(-0.3f, 1.0f, -0.05f)) * glm::rotate(phantomRotationMatrix_y, rotationAngle.y * glm::pi<float>() / 180.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(0.3f, -1.0f, -0.05f));
    phantomRotationMatrix_z = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(-0.3f, 1.0f, -0.05f)) * glm::rotate(phantomRotationMatrix_z, rotationAngle.z * glm::pi<float>() / 180.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(0.3f, -1.0f, -0.05f));

    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram.loadShaders("Shaders/phantom.vert", "Shaders/phantom.frag");

    glClearStencil(0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    shaderProgram.use();
    shaderProgram.setUniform("initialRotationMatrix", initialPhantomRotationMatrix);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("rotationMatrix_x", phantomRotationMatrix_x);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("rotationMatrix_y", phantomRotationMatrix_y);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("rotationMatrix_z", phantomRotationMatrix_z);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("model", model);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("view", view);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("projection", projection);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("lightColor", lightColor);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("lightPos", fpsCamera->getPosition());
    shaderProgram.setUniform("cameraPos", fpsCamera->getPosition());


    glStencilMask(0xFF); // Write to stencil buffer
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);  // Set any stencil to 0

    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF); // Set any stencil to object ID
    m_pantomMesh->draw();
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);  // Set any stencil to 0        // no need fot testing

    axisTransformation = glm::scale(axisTransformation, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    if (phantomIsSelected && leftMouseClicked)
    {
        shaderProgram.deleteProgram();
        shaderProgram.loadShaders("Shaders/arrow.vert", "Shaders/arrow.frag");
        shaderProgram.use();
        shaderProgram.setUniform("transform", axisTransformation);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("model", model);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("view", view);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("projection", projection);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);

        color = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // blue
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, 0xFF);
        m_phantomMeshArrows->drawZaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);

        color = glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // green
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 3, 0xFF);
        m_phantomMeshArrows->drawYaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);

        color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // red
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 4, 0xFF);
        m_phantomMeshArrows->drawXaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);
        shaderProgram.deleteProgram();
    }

    if (phantomIsSelected && rightMouseClicked)
    {
        shaderProgram.deleteProgram();
        shaderProgram.loadShaders("Shaders/arrow.vert", "Shaders/arrow.frag");
        shaderProgram.use();
        shaderProgram.setUniform("transform", axisTransformation);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("model", model);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("view", view);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("projection", projection);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);

        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 5, 0xFF);
        color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // red
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        m_phantomMeshArc->drawXaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);

        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 6, 0xFF);
        color = glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // green
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        m_phantomMeshArc->drawYaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);

        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 7, 0xFF);
        color = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // blue
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        m_phantomMeshArc->drawZaxis();
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);
        shaderProgram.deleteProgram();
    }

    if (positionAxisIsSelected)
    {
        plane->setPosition(planePosition);
        plane->setAxesAlignment(axesAlignment);
        color = glm::vec4(0.23f, 0.24f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transparent
        model = glm::mat4(1.0);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("model", model);
        shaderProgram.setUniform("color", color);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 5, 0xFF);
        plane->draw(fpsCamera->getCameraDirection()); // planeNormal returns correct result
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);
    }
    shaderProgram.deleteProgram();

    glFlush();
    wxGLCanvas::SwapBuffers();
}
```

As you can see my main loop is quite messy.

Question: how would you restructure it? Would you put axis (rotation and movement) draw calls in human class itself? Right now human class is just responsible for loading and drawing only human object.

Comment: did you look at the different openGL samples in wxWidgets?

Comment: @Igor I did look at several samples. However in those samples usually one or two objects are drawn.

Comment: Like any large program, separate out pieces that do very different things into very different functions or classes or packages. For example, I have separate functions for projection, calculating perspective ratios and stuff; viewpoint, where the digital camera or first person user is; and then finally drawing the scene or world. And the scene/world itself is usually a scene graph, a hierarchy of objects. Look for books or tutorials about "game engine design" or "scene graph organisation" for more ideas. (There's no One Right Answer)